# MongoDB jsonSchema validation additionalProperties

Tags: mongodb

**Create Collection with validator**

```
db.createCollection("claims", 
    { validator : { $jsonSchema : { bsonType : "object", 
                 properties : { airportCode : { bsonType: "string"} }, 
                 additionalProperties: false} 
                  } } )
```

**Insert**
`db.claims.insert({"airportCode" : "DSM"})` => result: "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"

if I remove "`additionalProperties: false`" by creating the collection, when I can insert the document.

Any advice, how to keep "`additionalProperties: false`", because I want to control the document.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As at MongoDB 3.6.2, JSON Schema validation does not automatically add the default `_id` property, so you need to include a rule for this when using `additionalProperties: false`.

For example, assuming the default ObjectID:

```
db.createCollection("claims",
    { validator : {
        $jsonSchema : {
            bsonType : "object",
            properties : {
                _id: { bsonType: "objectId" },
                airportCode : { bsonType: "string"}
            },
            additionalProperties: false
        }
     }}
)
```

Two related issues to upvote/watch on the MongoDB Jira issue tracker:

- [SERVER-32160: provide warning when _id is not in list of properties and additionalProperties is false](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32160)
- [SERVER-20547: Expose the reason an operation fails document validation](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20547)